# UTMREF/MGRS Grid over map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Did anyone knows a simple way to add a UTMREF/MGRS Grid over a leaflet map? (leaflet is not my problem)

I am not successful with the project https://github.com/pistell/Leaflet.DumbMGRS and there are to many issues years ago.

Maybe there is another plugin or a simple free public tile server?